# Create pandas timeseries with column frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a dataframe I have into a timeseries, which holds the frequency of `True` values for each column. The dataframe looks something like this:

```
    CREATED             A       B       C
0   2018-05-15 02:44:30 True    False   False
1   2018-05-15 06:57:18 True    False   False
2   2018-05-21 19:05:14 False   False   True
3   2018-05-21 10:15:07 False   True    False
4   2018-06-15 08:07:05 False   False   True
5   2018-06-15 14:07:05 True    False   True
```

For each row, only one of the columns is `True`, all other are `False`. I don't need the times, just the dates. The column **CREATED** is of type `datetime64[ns]`.
What I want is to prepare the dataframe to be able to plot a timeseries with lines for each column representing the frequency for each day/week/month.
The result I am have in my mind looks like this:

```
CREATED     A   B   C
2018-05-15  2   0   0
2018-05-21  0   1   1
2018-06-15  1   0   1
```

I tried to set the **CREATED** column as the index and resample as days, but I can't figure out how to concatenate everything to get the frequencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering `CREATED` is a `datetime` column, you can use `dt`, the datetime accessor, to access `date` like `series.dt.date`:

```
>>> df.groupby(df['CREATED'].dt.date).sum().reset_index()

      CREATED  A  B  C
0  2018-05-15  2  0  0
1  2018-05-21  0  1  1
2  2018-06-15  1  0  2
```

Otherwise, you can first convert `CREATED` to datetime column:

```
>>> df['CREATED'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CREATED'])
>>> df['CREATED'].dt.date

0    2018-05-15
1    2018-05-15
2    2018-05-21
3    2018-05-21
4    2018-06-15
5    2018-06-15
Name: CREATED, dtype: object
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I tried something similar but always ended up with exceptions. I probably messed up the brackets or position or something. Anyways thanks for the quick help